# Wordpress weird padding at the bottom of posts

Tags: css, wordpress, padding

I'm having issues with an empty container at the end of my WordPress posts body. I know what cause the problem and I tried to fix it but it somehow affects footer bottom padding too.

Here is the link:
https://oskvana.com/products/ansi-valves/class-300-bronze-globe-valve-with-npt-threaded-end-union-bonnet/

This is the code which causes the problem:

```css
.main-container .row-container .double-bottom-padding {
    padding-bottom: 72px;
}
```

Here what you see before I change the CSS code:

[image]

and when I change it to this:

```css
.main-container .row-container .double-bottom-padding {
    padding-bottom: 0px;
}
```

It fixes the problem but removes the bottom padding of the footer too.

Here's how:

[image]

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: The CSS rule you mentioned applies in multiple places - so you can not just change the value in there. But why is there an empty element with that class at the bottom of your product list to begin with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hessam

It looks like your issue is this class

".double-bottom-padding" included in your declaration:

```
.main-container .row-container .double-bottom-padding { padding-bottom: 72px; }
```

This class adds padding for the footer. If you'd like to remove the padding from ".main-container" but not ".double-bottom-padding", either remove ".main-container" from the above declaration or write an additional statement in your css

```
.double-bottom-padding { padding-bottom:72px }
```

Comment: Thank you Chris for answering fast, I removed ".main-container" but nothing changed. Since that weird container and footer are using the same class for padding I don't know how to write an additional statement.

Comment: Oops, excuse me - my mistake. It looks like the padding-bottom is actually 
".row-container".
Please disregard my above comment then set

 .row-container {padding-bottom:0}

Make sure that you write this statement  below the padding-bottom:72px statement so that it takes precedence in the CSS.

Comment: I tried this if I got correctly `.main-container .row-container .double-bottom-padding { 
    padding-bottom:72px
}
.row-container { 
    padding-bottom:0px
}` Nothing changed again.

Comment: Oh my gosh, I'm so sorry haha it's been a late-night - write it like this

.main-container .row-container .double-bottom-padding {      padding-bottom:72px }
.main-container .post-body .row-container .double-bottom-padding {padding-bottom:0}

where the additional .post-body will target the padding in the post section but not in the footer.